# Mockito Unit test for CharacterIterator loop

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have below code and need to write unit test for the same, however facing challenges while iterating over loop and testing it.current() and it.next().Really appreciate any help

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[length/2];
for(CharacterIterator it=new StringCharacterIterator(strVal);
    it.current() != CharacterIterator.DONE;
    it.next(), ++index) {
  final int rx = 16;
  final int left = Character.digit(it.current(), radix);
  final int right = Character.digit(it.next(), radix);
  buffer[index] = (byte) ((left << 4) + right);
}
}
```

I am quite new to Mokito hence unable to write proper tests. I tried few things below this doesn't work properly:

```
private Iterator<CharacterIterator> characterIterator=mock(Iterator.class);
MockedStatic<Character> character = Mockito.mockStatic(Character.class);
when(characterIterator.hasNext()).thenReturn(true);
when(characterIterator.next()).thenReturn(anyChar());
when(characterIterator.next().current()).thenReturn(anyChar());
character.when(()-> Character.digit(anyChar(), anyInt())).thenReturn(anyInt());
```

Comment: Please define _facing challenges_. Also, please show us the test you have now

Comment: You write a test where you provide a variable and expect something. Then, you should assert the result with the expected variable.

Comment: Why mocking this?? ..Couldn't you provide "just appropriate" `strVal` (s)!?

Comment: @xerx593 I would require to write test for loop and all it's sub conditions since I need to achieve 100% test coverage

Comment: if you cannot "reach" all sub conditions with (different) strVal(s), then re-consider their (sub conditions) "right to exist".

Comment: and since there is no try/catch in this code block... *and*: `.thenReturn(anyXXX());` (with the facts/static imports implied)  will return a (mockito) argument matcher, which is definitely wrong.